# How to add a new MIME/Protocol handler to firefox and chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, url, firefox, ubuntu, mime-types

So we created this application which handles a special protocol, now we want to open URLs that start with `xpc:?mcd` to be opened by a our application called `mscdopen`.

For this we added a `mscopen.desktop` file to the `/usr/share/application/` linking xpc to mscopen.

We noticed that `xgd-open` works perfectly. Soif we try `xgd-open xpc:>mcd115` it will open up in `mscopen`

How ever when we tried the same URL as links or directly in any google chrome or firefox the browsers responded saying it did not know how to handle the url types. Even after restarting the browser and the OS repeatedly.

Later we reinstalled firefox and then we noticed now it was prompting to open the URL in mscopen. The same happened  chrome.

So I would like to know if we can get the browsers to accept the new handle without having to reinstall the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding a .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`, run `sudo update-desktop-database` to refresh the database of MIME handlers.